# Using key title row to show value of stats variable

Tags: gnuplot

I want to use the key title row to show the maximum value of a stats result in gnuplot. I have this in my code:

```
...
set key box opaque samplen 2 at 30,60 \
title "Maximum="' sprintf("%.1fkW {/Symbol \\57} %.0frpm", Y_max, X_max)'
...
```

But this does not work, why?

Comment: The question has already been answered but next time please provide details about the error you are encountering as well, not just "does not work"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might want to put the `Maximum =` prefix in the `sprintf` call, i.e.,

```
set key box opaque samplen 2 at 30,60 \
title sprintf("Maximum = %.1fkW {/Symbol \\57} %.0frpm", Y_max, X_max)
```

This assumes that the variables `Y_max` and `X_max` are initialized. If it's not the case, one could use the `stats` command (e.g., `stats 'input_file.dat'`) before plotting and then employ the `STATS_max_y`/`STATS_max_x` variables which are automatically set by Gnuplot...